# Custom LCD display design considerations

Tags: design, lcd, display

I'm in the early stages of designing a device that will have a custom, backlit LCD display and an injection molded case.  I've never worked with a custom LCD display, and have not yet spoken with any manufacturers. The only known dimensions are the height and width of the glass. Are there standard dimensions that one should add to the glass dimensions?  If there are not, can I specify my required dimensions, or does the mfr. generally dictate the final module dimensions?  I'm considering COG and FPC.

Comment: You need to talk to the manufacturers, not us. Dave Jones ([EEVblog](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZYvxgl-9tNM)) recently did a custom LCD, so you might want to view his video to get some idea of the process.

Comment: @dave Tweed Yeah, it was his videos on the subject that led me to consider a custom LCD display.  Regarding your putting this question on hold, I'm simply asking experienced folk for specifics that Dave doesn't provide in his videos regarding module dimensions.  I'll edit to make the question more concise.  Regarding whether or not I should ask this question in this forum, I've asked similar questions here and received great answers.  I'm not an engineer and it's been my experience that engineers here are glad to share the kind of information I'm seeking.

Comment: I chatted with a manufacturer and got some useful information.  In very general terms, LED backlights overhang the glass by about 6.5-7mm on one or two edges, and pins or FPC require an additional 2mm on one or two edges.  Not sure if this is manufacturer-specific or universal.